# How to find the lowest temperature in this line.

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $ T (x, y) = 4x ^ 2 + 9y ^ 2$ represents a temperature distribution in the plane xy: $T (x, y)$ is the temperature, which we can suppose in Celsius, at the point (x, y).
Determine the lowest temperature point on the line $x + y = 1$

To solve this problem I thought that the lowest temperature point would be the intersection between the line x + y = 1 and the level curve formed by the curve $z = 4x ^ 2 + 9y ^ 2$, so the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of that point would have to be equal in both equations, so I isolate and I stayed with $y = 1 - x$.
However, by substituting this y in the equation of two variables, I arrived at the following absurdity:
$$4x² + 9 (1-x)²= 0$$
$$4x² + 9 (1-2x+x²)= 0$$
$$4x² + 9 -18x +9x²= 0$$
$$13x² -18x +9 = 0$$
$$ x = \frac{18 \pm \sqrt 324 - 468}{26} $$
I wonder if my reasoning is wrong or if I miss the calculations, and where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting for $y = 1-x$ was correct, but you don't have to solve for $x$, because that just gives you the point of which the 2 equations match, but not what you've been asked for.

Your new temperature, $T_{new}(x)$ after substituting becomes :

$$T_{new}(x) = 4x² + 9 (1-x)² = 13x² -18x +9  $$

To determine the "lowest temperature", we need to find the minima of this function, which is done by finding the derivative and its root :

$$T_{new}'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow 26x - 18 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 18/26$$

Then, you have : $y=1-x$, so :

$$y_{min} = 1 -x_{min} \Rightarrow y_{min} = 1 -18/26 = 7/26 $$

So, the point that the lowest temperature is observed over your given line is :

$$\bigg(\frac{18}{26},\frac{7}{26}\bigg)$$

We know that it's a minima since from the form and the signs of $T_{new}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $y = 1 -x$ to eliminate $y$ from the formula so it is a simple formula of just $x$.  Now, différentiation will easily find the minimum.